# 'Docker Desktop Stopping' showing in screen when I start the docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to start my docker by running shortcut of docker desktop but it shows the message Docker Desktop Stopping and never returns anything else.

Docker version gives me Docker version 20.10.16, build aa7e414

Docker build gives me this below error -

docker build .

```
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Post “http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&target=&ulimits=null&version=1”: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probably using Windows. To fix it, I had to make sure WSL 2 was installed properly:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package

If it's already installed on your machine, try uninstalling and reinstalling it.

Then, open Docker Desktop and click on the 'troubleshoot' icon in the top right corner. Click 'Clean/Purge Data' and select 'WSL 2' only and click 'delete'. Then restart your machine and it should work. Hope that helps!